# Overwriting an XML file and one of my nameSpace is missing

Tags: python, xml

I am parsing an XML file , replacing value on it and overwriting it, everything works fine but one of my two root's namespaces is missing after the overwrite.

I found that i have to register my namespaces, i did it but it doesnt change it:

There is the Xml file input :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding ="utf8"?>
<Document xmlns:xsi = "sample" xmlns ="sample2">
```

and there is the output :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Document xmlns="sample2">
```

there is when i register my namespace :

```
ET.register_namespace('xsi' , "sample")
ET.register_namespace('' , "Sample2" )
```

the writing method :

```
tree.write(path , xml_declaration=True, method='xml', encoding='UTF-8')
```

do you have any idea what is the problem and how can i fix it ?

Comment: So you’re usng ElementTree? Perhaps xsi isn’t used: does omitting this namespace this give any problem?

Comment: Yeah Xsi isnt used in my script , u think this is the problem ?

Comment: Omitting unused namespace doesn’t seem like a “problem”

Comment: Why do you needs to ensure your XML is cluettered with an unused namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably would be easier using lxml library:

```
from lxml import etree

nsmap = {'xsi': "sample", None: "sample2"}
root = etree.Element('Document', nsmap=nsmap)
print(etree.tostring(root))
```

Which gives desired output:

```
<Document xmlns:xsi="sample" xmlns="sample2"/>
```